# How to persist HDFS data in docker container

Tags: hadoop, docker, hdfs

I have a docker image for hadoop. (in my case it is https://github.com/kiwenlau/hadoop-cluster-docker, but the question applies to any hadoop docker image)

I am running the docker container as below..

```
sudo docker run -itd --net=hadoop --user=root -p 50070:50070 \
-p 8088:8088 -p 9000:9000 --name hadoop-master --hostname hadoop-master \
kiwenlau/hadoop
```

I am writing data to the hdfs file system from java running in the host ubuntu machine.

```
FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI(hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000"), configuration)
hdfs.create(new Path("hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000/user/root/input/NewFile.txt")),
```

**How should I mount the volume when starting docker such that the "NewFile1.txt" is persisted.**

**Which "path" inside the container corresponds to the HDFS path "/user/root/input/NewFile.txt" ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should inspect the `dfs.datanode.data.dir` in the hdfs-site.xml file to know where data is stored to the container filesystem

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:///root/hdfs/datanode</value>
    <description>DataNode directory</description>
</property>
```

Without this file/property, the default location would be in `file:///tmp/hadoop-${user.name}/dfs/data`

For docker,. mind that the default user that runs the processes is the root user.

You will also need to persist the namenode files, again seen  from that XML file

> Which "path" inside the container corresponds to the HDFS path "/user/root/input/NewFile.txt"

The container path holds the blocks of the HDFS file, not the whole file itself

Comment: Thank you v.much cricket_007
I looked up the datanode, namenode values from hdfs-site.xml.
I then mounted the directories in my docker run as follows.
 docker run -itd ..
  -v ~/mynamenode:/root/hdfs/namenode \
  -v ~/mydatanode:/root/hdfs/datanode \
  --privileged \

Now when I start the container, exec into it and issue the command
hadoop fs -mkdir test
I get the error
Call from hadoop-master/172.18.0.2 to hadoop-master:9000 failed on connection exception:
java.net.ConnectionException: Connection refused.

I am running the container in privileged mode.
Am I missing anything ?

Comment: Looks like a networking problem. If you are using Mac/Windows, the networking doesn't work like native Linux Docker containers

Comment: @Jzl people like spam downvoting me sometimes ;)

Comment: Thanks Mr.Cricket.. I got around that problem by using formatting the named node.   Your answer was spot on as far as my question was concerned and I see that the hdfs data was being persisted. I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: Am sorry, not sure why your answer was down voted.. its perfect.